# playing audio in JavaScript from URL with variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url, audio

What I'm trying to make is a input that when you type the song name it plays.
First what I tried was

```
function myFunction() {
  var id = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var audio = 'https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/' + id 
  var audio = new Audio ('audio');
 audio.play();
```

with the html code of

```
<input id="myInput" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">play</button>
```

Which didn't work

so I though what if I made it so

```
function myFunction() {
var id = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
var audio = new Audio 'https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/' + id;
audio.play();
```

to which is still didn't work. Does anybody have any idea on how to fix it so it works?

Edit: Im not good with json or even know what im doing btu would there be a possibilty to get the input from
`<input id="myInput" type="text"> <button onclick="myFunction()">play</button>`

and put it in json to then call the audio from the link
[https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/${song}.mp3](https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/$%7Bsong%7D.mp3)
with ${song} being the input from the html input

Comment: Rename your var into let, using var is outdated, even tho this is not the answer to your question, it will improve your performance ;) `let x = 1`...

Comment: @MaximilianDolbaum thank you for that little bit of advice :)

Comment: Is there a list of possible names?

Comment: yes you can find them in the code here https://github.com/Bobzilla07/Music_Tap/blob/master/index.html or you can find some of them here https://bobzilla07.github.io/Song_Music_Tap/

Comment: Neither of those are correct syntax...

first one you have `new Audio('audio')` which just passes in the string "audio", second one you have `new Audio 'https://...'` which should throw a syntax error

Comment: Also you should really sanitize and escape the input before pasting it into a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to pass the extension here as well. This does work because this server is CORS enabled.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", myFunction)
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  audio.src = 'https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/' + myInput.value + '.mp3';
  audio.play();
}
```

```css
audio { display:none;}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="myInput" value="Panic-Song">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<audio controls id="audio"></audio>
```

[Song list](https://github.com/Bobzilla07/Music_Tap)

Comment: Would i be able to use it without the controls?

Comment: Yes, just remove the `controls` attribute.

Comment: If I was to put a button so that when it starts playing (with contols hidden) what function would I have the button run? Also when removing the controls it doesnt play.

Comment: Then you have to wrap into a form, and listen for the `submit` event. Also used CSS to hide the player, it should still play everywhere. Note that into Firefox it was playing it's a cross browser issue. See the edit if you get confused. Good luck.

Comment: As you stated it says that a server is CORS enabled how would i get my github server to be cors enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let id = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
let audio = new Audio(`https://bobzilla07.github.io/Music_Tap/${id}.mp3`);
audio.play();
```

Now you can search for the file names of your songs. Like `1979` will play `1979.mp3`.

Comment: i found that this doesnt work it could just be me though